# Read four different values from an Arduino Infraredreceiver

Tags: arduino, infrared

I want to get 4 different values from an `Infraredreceiver`. Each call to the function `IRNumbers` should wait for an signal. But when it gets the first value, it continues and do not stop at the `while-loop`. It only uses the first value three more times..

Here is my code:

```cpp
int IRNumbers(int i) {
    char number;

    while (!irrecv.decode( & results));

    switch (results.value) {
        case 16738455:
            number = '0';
            break;

        case 16724175:
            number = '1';
            break;

        case 16718055:
            number = '2';
            break;

            ...

        default:
            IRNumbers(i);
            break;
    }
    return number;
}
```

I do not know why the `while-loop` doesn't stop. I tried clearing the buffer too. But it did nothing useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to call irrecv.resume() before you attempt to read the next value. For example:

```
int IRNumbers(int i) {
    char number;

    while (!irrecv.decode( & results));
    irrecv.resume();

    switch (results.value) {
        case 16738455:
            number = '0';
            break;

        ...
```